# Java Deployment with automatic updates (without user confirmation)

Tags: java, deployment, automation, update

Here in our company our users use 1 Java application which is updated every monday and always needs the latest java update. We install Java on Clients through SCCM 2012 R2.

I already know how to do this, the only thing i can't figure out is how to automatically update Java on computers.

This has to be silent, so we don't want users to get a pop up asking if they want to install the latest Java update. We want Java to autoupdate when users logon on monday morning, with no possibility to cancel it. (At least no obvious way to cancel it, so no cancel button or anything basic)

Been searching on google for a while now but most scenario's involve NOT wanting autoupdate.

Comment: Have you [extracted the MSI from the JRE installer](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/msi_install.xml)? Once you have the MSI, you can do whatever you like to install it -- Group Policy, logon script. We push JRE updates using [System Center Update Publiher](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/systemcenter/bb741049.aspx) (SCUP). This delivers Java along with "normal" Windows Udpates to our computers.

Comment: @jscott Yes, I'm using the MSI. We push java through OSD with SCCM, we also have a WSUS server, both SCCM and WSUS are still in a testing environment. Can I push this with WSUS? I don't know about SCUP? Is this free?

Comment: Sorry if i'm comming of as a noob, I'm doing an internship at a cityhall in belgium, and I have to setup OSD through SCCM and setup a WSUS server by myself with no experience what so ever, so I'm kinda lost. Anyway, the main goal is that JRE updates for both the x86 and x64 version are pushed automatically to clients silently, with no interaction from both clients and administrators. Is this possible? Do you have instructions on how to setup this update proces?

Comment: SCUP is free, click the link above. It will deliver third-party updates via WSUS or SCCM.